# Most latest result with separate group in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I have table data like below image.
[image]

Per we enter 6 records in 3times. (morning 2, afternoon 2, evening 2)

When I search by DATE, I want to get the result like below image.
[image]

I want to foreach that result like below.
[image]

I tried this sql query but no luck.

```
select c.currency, c.date, c.textbody
                from currencies c
                inner join (
                    select currency, max(date) as MaxDate
                    from currencies
                    group by currency
                ) cc on c.currency = cc.currency and c.date = cc.MaxDate
                where date ='2017-11-20'
                group by currency
                order by currency'
```

**Story of the Requirement** 
Per day user enter 6 records in 3 session of the time,  When the morning time user enter 2 records(EURUSD and GBPUSD). I will display then in a web page as one group. Then in the evening user enter another 2 records(EURUSD and GBPUSD), after that I need to show the latest 2 records are in the top group and previous 2 records and below. per day 6 records 3 groups.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? For each group (EURUSD and GBPUSD) .... ?? What exactly, because the result you print is not a typically SQL output..

Comment: second image show how I want the result.  then I can foreach by PHP.

Comment: then try add  a coherent sample of data in your result  ..

Comment: hi all, please check "Story of the Requirement" I added as my knowledge,  what I really want.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make simple query:

```
 SELECT currency, textBody FROM currencies 
 WHERE date = '2017-11-20'
 ORDER BY timestamp, currency
```

Then fetch the data to the `$rows` array, add a check to display only the paired rows and display them. In PHP this will be as follows:

```
$rowsCount = count($rows);

if (in_array($rowsCount, [2, 4, 6])) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsCount; $rowIndex++) {
        echo $rows[$i]['currency'] . ' ' . $rows[$i + 1]['currency'] . ' ' 
            . $rows[$i]['textbody'] . ' ' . $rows[$i + 1]['textbody'].PHP_EOL;
        $rowIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution,  I got idea from it. "for " should be 3 group.

Comment: @SampathSriAnuradha, did this help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you search for GROUP BY timestamp like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(currency) AS currencies, GROUP_CONCAT(text_body) AS text_bodyies, GROUP_CONCAT(timestamp) AS inserted_time
FROM currencies
WHERE date = '2017-11-20'
GROUP BY 
CASE 
    WHEN HOUR(timestamp) < 14 THEN 1 -- MORNING
    WHEN HOUR(timestamp) < 17 THEN 2 -- AFTERNOON
    WHEN HOUR(timestamp) < 21 THEN 3 -- EVENING
END
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: remove GROUP_CONCATs and GROUP BY and add a select of a field like this "CASE 
    WHEN HOUR(timestamp) < 14 THEN 'Morning'
    WHEN HOUR(timestamp) < 17 THEN 'Afternoon'
    WHEN HOUR(timestamp) < 21 THEN 'Evening'
END AS inserted_time"